# Ubuntu 14.04 Alt+Tab live preview selection issue

Tags: 14.04, unity, application-switcher

I have problem with graphical behavior of application switcher on Ubuntu 14.04.5. When I hit `Alt+Tab` and then `;` for live preview of selected application, it looks like its selection border starts to add next layout of itself over time, then, when selection border is nearly solid color around selected window for live preview, it starts from the beginning. How to revert its default behavioral? (or is it normal in Ubuntu 14.04?)

Sorry for my English.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are hitting the `;` for nor am I sure what you are asking. Note that you can get a screen full of default keyboard shortcuts by holding down the Super key.

Comment: When I hit `;` (together with pressed Alt) while I have open application switcher, I can see live preview of selected application. When live preview activates I can see orange border around this live preview (for imagination: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ubuntu+live+preview&t=canonical&iax=1&ia=images&iai=http%3A%2F%2F1.bp.blogspot.com%2F-Qg7GyCQrX_I%2FTpXIB6mDzfI%2FAAAAAAAABTY%2FCbc6ayMY7K8%2Fs1600%2FNew%2BUbuntu%2BApplication%2BSwitcher%2Bwith%2Bpreviews.png). This border contains alpha channel and when starts to stack, it looks like solid color without any alpha channel. I hope you understand.

Comment: Nope. Sorry, still don't get it. Simply holding the Alt key provides a live preview. Have you customized shortcuts to somehow use the ; ?

Comment: Okey, it doesn't matter how we get to live preview, the talk is about the border around live previewed application. Do you have the same problem (if you are using 14.04)? Flashing or ticking border.

Comment: Only when holding down the Alt key. Mine cycles slowly. It's keyboard repeat rate dependent (the rate is often adjustable in the BIOS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `;` has nothing to do with the issue. Holding down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key has this effect on my 14.04 as well. It cycles through what looks like 4 different border types with shadowing appearing ranging from none to fairly deep shadow surrounding the window in question. So to answer your question I believe this is the default behaviour.

I can confirm that showing seconds on the clock changes the behavior to cycling through 2 border types rather than 4.

Source: Testing

Comment: I got it! Thank you for your effort, but I found that it is caused by showing seconds on clock in system settings. Please, can you try it and report your behavior? It's very interesting ... probably bug ... ?